# How to set focus on default button group child element (after page load)

Tags: javascript

I have tried to set one of the buttons to `focus` or `active`, on clicking a separate 'switch' element (which makes the button group visible). This is long after the page has loaded, so `autofocus` won't do.

[link here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_button_group_vertical)
I can't seem to make it work. Perhaps the button element's focus cannot be triggered via a DOM selector.

I tried calling `focus()` on the element but that doesn't seem to work. I could loop through and do the styling for each element but it just seems like there must be a better way.

Please can someone suggest a way to do this? I would prefer a DOM-selector at this stage because I'm trying to become more familiar with it before moving on to jquery or other techniques.

Here is the html and CSS code:

```
<style>
.btn-group button {
  background-color: #b9b9b9; /* Green background, orange: #ffb748 */
  border: 1px solid grey; /* Green border, orange: #ffa00c */
  color: white; /* White text */
  padding: 10px 24px; /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
  width: 50%; /* Set a width if needed */
  display: block; /* Make the buttons appear below each other */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}

/* Add a background color on hover, focus & reset on blur */
.btn-group button:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
.btn-group button:focus {
  background-color: grey;
}
.btn-group button:blur {
  background-color: #b9b9b9 /*#4CAF50*/;
}

</style>


<div style="width: 50%">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button id="one">Apple</button>
      <button id="two">Samsung</button>
      <button id="three">Sony</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and from within the browser console:

```
document.querySelector('#one').focus();
```

Comment: Share your html code

Answer (score 1):

`.focus()` should work fine, see below snippet.

Are you sure you're calling the JS from the right place?
And is the query definitely finding an element?
You can `console.log` the result of the query before calling `focus` to see.

```js
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('#one').focus(), 1000);
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('#two').focus(), 2000);
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('#three').focus(), 3000);
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('#one').focus(), 4000);
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('#two').focus(), 5000);
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('#three').focus(), 6000);
```

```css
.btn-group button {
  background-color: #b9b9b9;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}

.btn-group button:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.btn-group button:focus {
  background-color: grey;
}

.btn-group button:blur {
  background-color: #b9b9b9;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 50%">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button id="one">Apple</button>
    <button id="two">Samsung</button>
    <button id="three">Sony</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right you are.  I should have tried invoking the method from within the script tag. When calling it from the browser dev tools console, it doesn't work. opera and chrome, I've tried. Just thinking about it, now... that may be because the console has the focus.

Comment: Yes... that was the problem. If I set the timeout to 3 seconds, run it from the console, then just after running it, shift the focus to the browser window, instead, it then works. Thanks, Luke.